# What ColdFusion forum applications were designed to be embedded into existing applications?

Tags: coldfusion, forum

I'm looking to "embed" a forum into an existing website. I've talked to Ray about what it'd take to do this with Galleon (a great CF-based forum), and it's doable.

As part of due diligence, I'd like to know if any existing ColdFusion-based forum software was designed with embeddedness in mind; in other words, forum software that wasn't built to just be run as a standalone application.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you check RIAForge? I think there are a couple forum options up there.

Comment: Yessir. I only found one that *might* work, but it was meant to be standalone and obviously is nowhere near as nice as Galleon :-)

Comment: I really thought there were more. Hey - there is a commercial one. I forget the name - it is an old one that recently relaunched.... grr... can't remember.

Comment: Ahah, Fusetalk. Not sure if it is any good or embedable either - but it's another option.

Comment: I shall check that out. Thanks, Ray

Answer (score 0):

Marc, if you're looking for an add-on to a Mura CMS site, you should check out Meld Forums - https://github.com/meldsolutions/Meld-Forums. Free, open-source, etc.